# Получить числа из rgba (число, число, число, число) через regexp

Tags: javascript, строки

Нужно получить числа из `rgba (число, число, число, число)` используя `RegExp`.  Числа должны выводится не в виде отделных чисел, а в виде полного числа.

То есть не [2],[2],[5],[ ],[3],[1] а [225],[ ],[31]

Comment: `rgba \((\d{1,3}),\s*(\d{1,3}),\s*(\d{1,3}),\s*(\d*(?:\.\d+)?)\)`

Answer (score 1):

Нужно использовать `.match(/\d+/g)`. `\d` найдет числа, а `+` найдет и склеит числа идущие подряд.